# How can I connect arducopter to Raspberry Pi?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, ardupilot

This is my school project. I would like *arducopter* to connect to Raspberry  Pi but I do not know how to do it. Please help me!

Comment: you have to explain what this means exactly `arducopter connect to raspberry` ...... also explain what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I want to see the gps data from arducopter at raspberrypi

Answer (score 0):

To do so, you need to use a USB link between the Ardupilot/Arducopter and use the MAVLink protocol to interrogate the Arducopter in order that it sends back its GPS data. You can etheir way use the C libs of MAVLink, the Python implementation or the ROS one (named mavros). You may find some clues here:

- [MAVLink dev guide](https://mavlink.io/en/)
- [Python implementation - the easier one to handle](https://github.com/ArduPilot/pymavlink)

Depending on your programming skills this may requires you some time to reach your aim!